# xfce icons instead of tabs

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, appearance, taskbar

For my taskbar programs are displayed like:

(symbol of chromium)askubuntu.com

I would like it as:

> symbol of chromium [no titles]
>
> askubuntu.com
>
> imagemagick man page

Like in cinnamon or windows 7. No annoying long titles. Displaying whichever window by title whenever I click on the symbol.

I am running xfce xubuntu x64 tried a ton of different options in the settings manager, but cannot locate it, if it is there. How would I go about doing this so my desktop doesn't look like a complete mess?

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured it out. Posted in case anyone has trouble with this.

Two solutions:

Right click panel> Panel Preferences> Mode> Deskbar

If horizontal mode is to be selected then go to the items section > Window Buttons and uncheck show button labels.

Comment: The deskbar works fine on XFCE 4.16, but the horizontal mode does not seems to have the "show button labels" option anymore. Has the feature been dropped?